# are two sets of infinity necessarily equal | Automata

Tags: equivalence-relations, infinity, automata, regular-language

we'll define the relation $\equiv_L$ (same one as the one in [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cot4210/spring04/assignments/Myhill-Nerode_Theorem.html#:%7E:text=The%20Myhill%2DNerode%20Theorem%20states,equivalence%20classes%20in%20RL.)) as follows:

> there exists two string $x,y$ and a language $L$ under the $\Sigma$ alphabet

> $x\equiv_Ly$ if there $\nexists$ a suffix $\sigma$ where $x\sigma \in L$ and $y\sigma \notin L$

> $x\not\equiv_L y$ if there $\exists$ a suffix $\sigma$ where $x\sigma \in L$ and $y\sigma \notin L$

> **Rank(L) = number of equivalence classes under the relation $≡_L$**

> Rank(L) also equal to the number of states in the minimal DFA

let there be $L$ above the binary alphabet and $L^R$ - it's reverse.

**is the following statement true or false:**

> if $L$ is not regular than $Rank(L)=Rank(L^R)$

I answered false because as I understand the rank of a non-regular language may equal to infinity, However, there are different sizes of infinity, known as cardinalities. For example, the cardinality of the set of real numbers  is larger than the cardinality of the set of natural numbers. so you can't say that $\infty=\infty$ necessarily.

they claim the statement is true...are they right?

Comment: What is the rank of a language?

Comment: @MeesdeVries the number of equivalence classes in L, for regular languages - it is equal to the number of states in the minimum DFA

Comment: Equivalence classes under what equivalence relation?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it's not the number of words

Comment: @MeesdeVries I'm talking about distinguishable classes - between every 2 classes there exists a symbol where concatenating that symbol makes one class of words in L and one not in L.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Rank(L) = number of equivalence classes under the relation ≡L

Comment: I still do not understand what the equivalence relation is.

Comment: @MeesdeVries edited my post, hope this clears it up...

Comment: Yes, there are different sizes of infinity, but that doesn't mean that these two particular infinities are of different sizes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you're right, but what I'm saying is that they're not necessarily equal.

Comment: In this case, the set of finite words over a finite alphabet is countable, which is the smallest kind of infinity. So if they are both infinite, then they are also of the same size. Does that answer the question?

Comment: But, Skynet, these are not just any old infinite sets, they are closely related to each other. Indeed, one is defined in terms of the other. It could be that's enough to construct a proof they're of the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that your question is poorly stated and your definition of the Nerode equivalence is wrong. Here are a few advices.

First, try to use some homogeneous notation. If you use $x, y$ for strings, it would be best to use a roman letter, say $s$, for a suffix. Especially, since you denote by $\Sigma$ the alphabet, it is tempting to interpret $\sigma$ as a letter.

Next, you should avoid using existential quantifiers inside an English sentence. I guess you wanted to say

> $x \equiv_L y$ if there is no suffix $\sigma$ such that $x\sigma \in L$ and $y\sigma \notin L$

Unfortunately, this definition is wrong. For instance, if $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, $L = \{0\}$, $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, there is no $s$ such that $1s \in L$ and $0s \notin L$. However $0 \not\equiv_L 1$.

The right definition should be

> $x \equiv_L y$ if, for each $s \in \Sigma^*$, $xs \in L$ if and only if $ys \in L$.

Now, coming back to your question, any language $L$ on a finite alphabet is accepted by the infinite deterministic automaton ${\cal A}_L = (\Sigma^*, \Sigma, \cdot, \varepsilon, L)$ in which $\Sigma^*$ is the set of states, $\Sigma$ is the alphabet, the initial state is the empty string and the set of final states is $L$. The transitions are defined, for each state $u$ and every letter $\sigma$, by $u \cdot \sigma = u \sigma$.

Since $\Sigma$ is finite, $\Sigma^*$ is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set). Thus $L$ is recognized by a countable deterministic automaton. Therefore, its minimal automaton, which is a quotient of ${\cal A}_L$ is also countable. If $L$ is non-regular,
its minimal automaton is infinite countable.

As you know, $L$ is regular if and only if $L^R$ is regular. If this is the case, their minimal automaton are both finite (but in general not the same number of states). If they are both non regular, then, as said above, their minimal automaton are both infinite countable.